# Sort SQL JOIN results in PHP arrays

Tags: php, mysql, join, multidimensional-array

I got 2 relational tables:

```
table "categories"
id int(11)
title varchar(255)

table "posts"
id int(11)
title varhcar(255)
category_id int(11) // foreign key
```

If I select the "categories" table, I would like to get a PHP array with al the categories (as in "SELECT * categories") but including an inner array with all its posts:

```
Array (
    /* first category */
    [0] = Array (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => "Rock"
        /* all its posts */
        [posts] => Array (
            [0] = Array(
                [id] = 100
                [title] = "Rock post title"
                [category_id] = 1
            )
            [1] = Array(
                [id] = 101
                [title] = "Other rock post title"
                [category_id] = 1
            )
     )
    /* second category */
    [1] = Array (
    )
/* ... */
)
```

If I just made a "join" query I get all the results combined, something like:

```
id     title    id    title               category_id
1      Rock     100   "Rock post title"   1
2      Rock     101   "Other rock post"   1
3      Rock     102   "Final rock post"   1
```

I don't want to make multiple queries, because I think is inefficient.

Is there anyway to achive the desire result with one query?

I know CakePHP manage to return relational tables results in this format, so I'm looking to achieve the same result.

Comment: the join query is fine, you just then need to loop through th e results to create you desired array structure.

Answer (score 0):

The join should look something like:

```
select c.id, c.title, p.id, p.title, p.category_id 
from categories c, posts p
where c.id = p.category_id 
order by c.id, p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want this functionality consider using an ORM library (such as what CakePHP and other frameworks provide) rather than rolling your own code for a problem that's already been solved.

You cannot do 'inner arrays' in SQL, not without great ugliness (like packing records into a string column then unpacking them in PHP).

But for a quick 'n dirty solution, just use your original join query as long as you rename the post id and title (eg, 'post_id') in the query to avoid confusion with category id. Then loop over the resultset and build your array.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($resultset as $row) {
    if(!array_key_exists($row['category_id'],$newArray)) {
       $newArray[$row['category_id']] = array('id' => $row['category_id'], 'title' => $row['title'], 'posts' => array());
    }
    $newArray[$row['category_id']]['posts'] = array('id' => $row['post_id'], 'title' => $row['post_title'], 'category_id' => $row['category_id']);
}
```

I didn't write this code in an editor so I apologize for typos. You get the general idea.